# Is Any Audio Is Playing? (In Android)

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I've two activities in my app, first one (MainActivity.java) has a button to call activity two (player.java) and the second one has the audio and a stop button.

So the main problem I'm facing is..

when I click start second activity from one it goes to another activity,
as i programmed it starts audio automatically (I Want It To Start Automatically) I press stop audio stops... then go back to MainActivity call second activity (player.java) again it works fine... again it starts audio correctly... everything is working fine when I press back the audio keeps playing on... (That's What i Want)

But, if press back without stopping the audio, and start the second activity (player.java) again, it starts the audio again without stopping first one... and same track plays two times...

I want to play only one track at once... if any other audio is playing, stop it, when I start that activity again.

Here is My Code...

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.test.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedIntanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedIntanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        public void clicked(View v){
            if (v.getId() == R.id.button){
              Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, player.class);
              startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**player.java**

```
package com.test.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.media.*;

public class player extends Activity {
  Button stop;
  MediaPlayer audio;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedIntanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedIntanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);

        stop= (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        audio = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.myAudio);
        audio.start();

        public void stop(View v){
            if (v.getId() == R.id.stop){
                audio.stop();
                audio = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.myAudio);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: My Code Is Too Long... So I Trimmed Off The Other Stuff.. And Just Shared Where I'm Getting The Problem... Please Check It Out And If You Can Help Me So Please Dude... I'm Waiting.........

Comment: Try overriding `onBackPressed()` in your `PlayerActivity.java` and stop media player there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your MediaPlayer object static & check for Mediaplayer isPlaying(). Try

```
public class player extends Activity {
    Button stop;
    static MediaPlayer audio;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedIntanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedIntanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                audio.stop();
            }
        });

        if(audio == null) {
            audio = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.myaudio);
            audio.start();
        } else {
            if(audio.isPlaying()) {
                audio.stop();
                audio = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.myaudio);
                audio.start();
            } else {
                audio = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.myaudio);
                audio.start();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Voohooooo...!!!!!!!! You Made My Day Dude....... Superb! It Worked... You're Awesome Thankssssss................